Can communication networks be simulated in modelica?

I'm trying to evaluate if modelica can be used for implementing models of complex industrial systems in order to validate their components before deploying them. One of the critical aspects that need to be verified is the conformance of their interfaces to specific protocols, so we can't just simulate their mechanical and electrical behaviour.
As a consequence, I'm trying to find if a communication network could be implemented using just modelica (e.g. a simplifyied GNS3 style simulation). However, every paper I've found solves this by calling external C libraries.
Can something like that be achieved?
Previous work:
A communication network can be simulated as a set of components that send and receive messages (synchronously or asynchronously depending on the protocol). In order to achieve that, a buffer is needed to store the received messages until they can be processed. That can be achieved using an algorithm. E.g. a simple ring buffer can be implemented as follows:
package MSGlib
type Status = enumeration(empty, unread, read, error);
type Priority = enumeration(normal, urgent);
record message "Base type for defining messages"
  Status s;
  String Header;
  Priority p;
  String Body;
end message;
model ringBuffer
  message newMSG;
  message readMSG;
  protected
    message msg[10];
    Integer firstMSG (start = 1);
    Integer lastMSG (start = 1);
    Integer currentMSG (start = 1);
  algorithm
    if newMSG.s == Status.unread then
      currentMSG := lastMSG;
      if currentMSG == 10 then
        currentMSG := 1;
      else
        currentMSG := currentMSG + 1;
      end if;
      if not(currentMSG == firstMSG) then
        msg[currentMSG] := newMSG;
        newMSG.s := Status.read;
      else
        newMSG.s := Status.error;
      end if;
    end if;
  algorithm
    if readMSG.s == Status.read then
      if lastMSG == 1 then
        lastMSG := 10;
      else
        lastMSG := lastMSG - 1;
      end if;
      readMSG := msg[lastMSG];
    elseif readMSG.s == Status.empty then
      readMSG := msg[lastMSG];
    end if;
end ringBuffer;
end MSGlib;

However, it seems that modelica doesn't support using records as model input/output variables. Is there any workaround to exchange complex data between models?
Edit 17/09/2024:
It seems to be possible to implement connectors that include records. Therefore, I've modified the previous code to implement the input and output messages using connectors. However, I'm not sure if this is an adequate approach:
package MSGlib
type Status = enumeration(empty, unread, read, error);
type Priority = enumeration(normal, urgent);
record message "Base type for defining messages"
  Status s;
  String Header;
  Priority p;
  String Body;
end message;

connector MSGPin
  discrete message MSG;
  annotation(
      Icon(graphics = {Rectangle(fillColor = {0, 170, 0}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})}));
end MSGPin;

model ringBuffer
  input MSGPin newMSG annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {-84, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-88, 0}, extent = {{-46, -46}, {46, 46}})));
  output MSGPin readMSG annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {86, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}), iconTransformation(origin = {87, -1}, extent = {{-45, -45}, {45, 45}})));
  protected
    message msg[10];
    Integer firstMSG (start = 1);
    Integer lastMSG (start = 1);
    Integer currentMSG (start = 1);
  algorithm
    if newMSG.MSG.s == Status.unread then
      currentMSG := lastMSG;
      if currentMSG == 10 then
        currentMSG := 1;
      else
        currentMSG := currentMSG + 1;
      end if;
      if not(currentMSG == firstMSG) then
        msg[currentMSG] := newMSG.MSG;
        newMSG.MSG.s := Status.read;
      else
        newMSG.MSG.s := Status.error;
      end if;
    end if;
  algorithm
    if readMSG.MSG.s == Status.read then
      if lastMSG == 1 then
        lastMSG := 10;
      else
        lastMSG := lastMSG - 1;
      end if;
      readMSG.MSG := msg[lastMSG];
    elseif readMSG.MSG.s == Status.empty then
      readMSG.MSG := msg[lastMSG];
    end if;
annotation(
      Icon(graphics = {Rectangle(extent = {{-80, -80}, {80, 80}}), Polygon(origin = {0, 50}, points = {{0, -30}, {-80, 30}, {80, 30}, {80, 30}, {0, -30}})}));
end ringBuffer;
end MSGlib;

Edit 18/09/2024:
Simulation of synchronous communication protocols seems possible. However, asynchronous communications seem more complex to simulate using modelica, as a fully discrete event simulation would be required ('when' clausses seem to misbehave when used in algorithms with conditions that aren't based on clock signals):
MSGlib implementation:
package MSGlib
type Status = enumeration(empty, unread, read, error);
type Priority = enumeration(normal, urgent);
record message "Base type for defining messages"
  Status s (start = Status.empty);
  String Header (start = "");
  Priority p (start = Priority.normal);
  String Body (start = "");
end message;

connector MSGPin
  discrete message MSG;
  annotation(
      Icon(graphics = {Rectangle(fillColor = {0, 170, 0}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})}));
end MSGPin;

model ringBuffer
  input MSGPin newMSG annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {-84, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-88, 0}, extent = {{-46, -46}, {46, 46}})));
  output MSGPin readMSG annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {86, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}), iconTransformation(origin = {87, -1}, extent = {{-45, -45}, {45, 45}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanInput u annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {-84, -50}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, -58}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})));
  Integer stored_messages (start = 0);
  Boolean receiving (start = false);
  
    message msg[10];
    Integer firstMSG (start = 1);
    Integer lastMSG (start = 1);

  algorithm
  for i in 1:10 loop
    msg[i].s := msg[i].s;
    msg[i].Header := msg[i].Header;
    msg[i].Body := msg[i].Body;
    msg[i].p := msg[i].p;
  end for;
  if change(u) and u == true then
    receiving := true;
    if newMSG.MSG.s == Status.unread then
      if stored_messages <= 10 then
        lastMSG := firstMSG + stored_messages;
        if lastMSG > 10 then
          lastMSG := lastMSG -10;
        end if;
        msg[lastMSG].s := newMSG.MSG.s;
        msg[lastMSG].Header := newMSG.MSG.Header;
        msg[lastMSG].Body := newMSG.MSG.Body;
        msg[lastMSG].p := newMSG.MSG.p;
        stored_messages := stored_messages + 1;
      else
        stored_messages := stored_messages;
        lastMSG := lastMSG;
      end if;
    end if;
    if (readMSG.MSG.s == Status.empty) and (stored_messages > 0) then
      readMSG.MSG.s := msg[firstMSG].s;
      readMSG.MSG.Header := msg[firstMSG].Header;
      readMSG.MSG.Body := msg[firstMSG].Body;
      readMSG.MSG.p := msg[firstMSG].p;
    elseif (readMSG.MSG.s == Status.read) and (stored_messages > 0) then
      firstMSG := firstMSG + 1;
      if firstMSG > 10 then
        firstMSG := firstMSG - 10;
      end if; 
      readMSG.MSG.s := msg[firstMSG].s;
      readMSG.MSG.Header := msg[firstMSG].Header;
      readMSG.MSG.Body := msg[firstMSG].Body;
      readMSG.MSG.p := msg[firstMSG].p;
    end if;
  else
    receiving := false;
  end if;
annotation(
      Icon(graphics = {Rectangle(extent = {{-80, -80}, {80, 80}}), Polygon(origin = {0, 50}, points = {{0, -30}, {-80, 30}, {80, 30}, {80, 30}, {0, -30}})}));
end ringBuffer;

model sender
  output MSGPin readMSG annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {86, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}), iconTransformation(origin = {87, -1}, extent = {{-45, -45}, {45, 45}})));
  parameter String Header;
  parameter String Body;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanInput u annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {-86, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})));
  Boolean sending (start = false);
algorithm
  if u == true then
  readMSG.MSG.Header := Header;
  readMSG.MSG.Body := Body;
  readMSG.MSG.s := Status.unread;
  readMSG.MSG.p := Priority.normal;
  sending := true;
  else
  readMSG.MSG.Header := "";
  readMSG.MSG.Body := "";
  readMSG.MSG.s := Status.empty;
  readMSG.MSG.p := Priority.normal;
  sending := false;
  end if;
annotation(
      Icon(graphics = {Rectangle(extent = {{-80, -80}, {80, 80}}), Polygon(origin = {0, 40}, points = {{0, -40}, {80, 40}, {-80, 40}, {0, -40}, {0, -40}}), Polygon(origin = {30, -40}, points = {{-10, 20}, {10, 0}, {-10, -20}, {-10, 20}, {-10, 20}}), Line(origin = {-20, -40}, points = {{40, 0}, {-40, 0}, {-40, 0}}), Line(origin = {-60, -40}, points = {{0, -20}, {0, 20}, {0, 20}})}));
end sender;

  model reader
    input MSGPin newMSG annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {-84, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-88, 0}, extent = {{-46, -46}, {46, 46}})))
  ;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanInput u annotation(
      Placement(transformation(origin = {-82, -62}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, -60}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})));
  String MSG_body;
  algorithm
    when (change(u) and (u == true)) then
      //newMSG.MSG.s := Status.read;
      MSG_body := newMSG.MSG.Body;
    end when;
  annotation(
        Icon(graphics = {Rectangle(extent = {{-80, -80}, {80, 80}}), Polygon(origin = {0, 40}, points = {{0, -40}, {80, 40}, {-80, 40}, {0, -40}, {0, -40}}), Polygon(origin = {30, -40}, points = {{-10, 20}, {10, 0}, {-10, -20}, {-10, 20}, {-10, 20}}), Line(origin = {-20, -40}, points = {{40, 0}, {-40, 0}, {-40, 0}}), Line(origin = {40, -40}, points = {{0, -20}, {0, 20}, {0, 20}})}));
  end reader;
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end MSGlib;

Code used for testing that library:
(Notice that the library has some bugs, as it isn't able to notify the buffer when a message has been read in order to delete it)
model MSGlib_test
  MSGlib.sender sender(Header = "hjdukavf", Body = "kvfku")  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-46, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  MSGlib.reader reader annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {36, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interaction.Show.BooleanValue booleanValue annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-44, 38}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Clocked.BooleanSignals.TimeBasedSources.Pulse pulse1(period = 2)  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-88, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  MSGlib.ringBuffer ringBuffer annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-10, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
equation
  connect(pulse1.y, sender.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-76, 0}, {-54, 0}}, color = {255, 0, 255}));
  connect(pulse1.y, reader.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-76, 0}, {-66, 0}, {-66, -24}, {16, -24}, {16, -6}, {28, -6}}, color = {255, 0, 255}));
  connect(pulse1.y, booleanValue.activePort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-76, 0}, {-66, 0}, {-66, 38}, {-56, 38}}, color = {255, 0, 255}));
  connect(ringBuffer.readMSG, reader.newMSG) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-1, 0}, {28, 0}}));
  connect(sender.readMSG, ringBuffer.newMSG) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-38, 0}, {-19, 0}}));
  connect(ringBuffer.u, pulse1.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-16, -6}, {-30, -6}, {-30, -24}, {-66, -24}, {-66, 0}, {-76, 0}}, color = {255, 0, 255}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end MSGlib_test;

